# accessing stored locale from angular-translate FileStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I am using [angular-translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/10_storages) with LocalStorage and it works very well.  Locales are cached or stored on local disk.  When the browser is closed and re-launched the chosen locale is persisted.

My question is how can I access that *cached* or *stored* locale that's on disk in one of my controllers?  To better explain here's the workflow that is **not** working:

```
1. Launch browser to localhost and can see the site with previously chosen locale
2. Attempt to access the current locale from either the
    2.1 $translate.proposedLanguage()
    2.2 tmhDynamicLocale
3. Both are undefined -- even though the correct language is shown
4. Select language choice once more
5. current locale from both the above is now correct
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vtszeu3v/4/) for the module and locale service.  Not **runnable** code.  Just an example of the code I'm using

I am trying to access `currentLocale` but it is **undefined** until the user makes a selection (again).  I know it's stored somewhere since the original selection is persisted after browser exit.

Comment: It's just a paste of the code and not intended to be working example!

Comment: Make the question shorter! It's a lot of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After about 2 hours in a rabbit whole of API docs and angular-translate-* sources files I found that I can pass `$translateLocalStorage` to my controller and then call `$translateLocalStorage.get()` which will return that cached localId.

That method pulls the localId from `$window.localStorage.getItem.  That code is

```
get: function (name) {
    if(!langKey) {
      langKey = $window.localStorage.getItem(name);
    }

    return langKey;
  }
```

So all you would need to do is:

```
angular.module('myModule')
  .controller('QueryController', function($scope, es, $translateLocalStorage) {
     $scope.show_results = function(results) {
        var currentLocale = $translateLocalStorgae.get();
 }
});
```